# How $scope.gridOptions.data works to convert other data

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

For example:
In ui grid table the data will be shown by the column model " firstname" "lastname " "age"

when a data from Database has a null value like {firstname:"test", lastname:"test",age:null }
what will hapen in ui grid table? will it show nothing? how toavoid this?

Comment: What do you want to happen when value is null? e.g. Have some placeholder text 'Not available'?

Comment: I have solved it by replacing the null data once receiving the data from server, thank you